# How to diagnose CPU performance problems?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, performance, hardware

Recently I bought a new netbook based on AMD A4-1200 CPU and installed Linux Mint 17 with XFCE. RAM is 4GB

So, testing some of my programs, I found very strange behavior. On random intervals, the computer becomes at least twice slower than usual.

For example a program that executed for 1500ms, begins to execute for 3000 or even 4000ms. The test program is short living, console program and process data in memory, using only one of the CPU cores. I am measuring only the time when the program works in memory, without any disk or other HW access.

Testing some other programs (gzip for example), revealed the same slow down of more than twice.

After reboot the problem disappears for some random period.

The task manager indicates 5..10% CPU, 15% RAM and 0% swap usage.

There is no processes that to use the CPU intensively in these moments.

I tried to set the CPU frequency governor from "ondemand" to "performance" but nothing changed. (Only the CPU temperature raised with 2 degrees from 70 to 72 deg Celsius).

**So, the question:** What happens? How to diagnose the problem? What I missed to notice?

Comment: You could definitely find lots of information from [here](http://www.slideshare.net/brendangregg/linux-performance-analysis-and-tools). Hopefully, any one of the methods discussed in that might help you out.